# A question about discrete subsets of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

A subset $ D $ of a topological space $ X $ is called **discrete** if and only if for each point $ x \in D $, there is an open neighborhood $ U $ of $ x $ such that $ U \cap D = \{ x \} $.

My question is:

> **Question:** Given a discrete subset $ D $ of a space $ X $, can we find a $ D $-indexed sequence $ (U_{x})_{x \in D} $ of open subsets of $ X $ such that $ x \in U_{x} $ for each $ x \in D $ and $ U_{x} \cap U_{y} = \varnothing $ for distinct $ x,y \in D $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no. Consider a T<sub>1</sub> but not Hausdorff space $X$. Then there are points $x,y \in X$ which cannot be separated by disjoint open sets. However $X \setminus \{ y \}$ and $X \setminus \{ x \}$ are open neighbourhoods of $x,y$, respectively, which meet $\{ x , y \}$ in only one point.

Even if you consider Hausdorff spaces this need not be true. The property you are talking about is close to [collectionwise Hausdorffness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectionwise_Hausdorff_space) (you would additionally need to require that $D$ is closed). An example of a Hausdorff (even normal) space which is not collectionwise Hausdorff is Bing's Example G, which is described in [this blog post of Dan Ma](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/bings-example-g/).

The [Moore plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane) would be a more familiar example of a Hausdorff space which is not collectionwise Hausdroff. Here the $x$-axis $D = \{ (x,0) : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is a closed discrete subset for which there is no family $\{ U_x : x \in D \}$ of disjoint open sets such that $x \in U_x$ for each $x \in D$.